# psql, display column that is not in the group by clause

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregation

i'm having problems with a query. I have two tables: country and city and i want to display the city with the highest population per country.

Here's the query:

```
select country.name as coname, city.name as ciname, max(city.population) as pop 
    from city 
    join country on city.countrycode=country.code 
    group by country.name 
    order by pop;`
```

Error

> column "city.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

I don't know how to solve this, i tried to make a subquery but it didn't work out.
How can i make it work?

Comment: To resolve your error, you have to add `city.name` to the `group by`. But i don't know if it will give you the correct result, you have to show the two tables definition, and some data sample

Comment: If i add city.name to the group by it will show all ciites of a country

Comment: You can easly use: [rank](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html) window function to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easly get it using **[rank](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html)** function:

```
select * from
(
select country.name as coname, 
 city.name as ciname, 
 city.population, 
 rank() over (partition by country.name order by city.population desc) as ranking 
from 
    city 
join 
    country 
on city.countrycode=country.code 
 ) A
 where ranking = 1
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, what does the fourth column "ranking" mean?

Comment: It is a caluclated column ( `ranking` is just an alias name), it gives the rank of the country's cities depending on its population. Please see the documentation for more detail